# Editing all text in childNodes of XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml, text, edit

I'm trying to edit the text inside of all of the tags named "Volume" in an XML file by multiplying that text by a number entered by the user. The text inside of the "Volume" tag will always be a number. My code works so far, but only on the first instance of the "Volume" text.

Here's an example of the XML:

```
         <blah>
                <moreblah> sometext </moreblah> ;
                <blah2>
                        <blah3> <blah4> 30 </blah4> <Volume> 15 </Volume> </blah3>
                </blah2>
        </blah>

         <blah>
                <moreblah> sometext </moreblah> ;
                <blah2>
                        <blah3> <blah4> 30 </blah4> <Volume> 25 </Volume> </blah3>
                </blah2>
        </blah>
```

And here's my Python code:

```
#import modules
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import os
import fileinput

#create a backup of original file
new_file_name = 'blah.xml'
old_file_name = new_file_name + "_old"
os.rename(new_file_name, old_file_name)

#find all instances of "Volume"
doc = parse(old_file_name)
volume = doc.getElementsByTagName('Volume')[0]
child = volume.childNodes[0]
txt = child.nodeValue

#ask for percentage input
print
percentage = raw_input("Set Volume Percentage (1 - 100): ")
if percentage.isdigit():
    if int(percentage) <101 >1:
        print 'Thank You'

        #append text of <Volume> tag
        child.nodeValue = str(int(float(txt) * (int(percentage)/100.0)))

        #persist changes to new file
        xml_file = open(new_file_name, "w")
        doc.writexml(xml_file)
        xml_file.close()

        #remove XML Declaration
        text = open("blah.xml", "r").read()
        text = text.replace('<?xml version="1.0" ?>', '')  
        open("blah.xml", "w").write(text)


    else:

        print
        print 'Please enter a number between 1 and 100.'
        print 
        print 'Try again.'
        print
        print 'Exiting.'


        xml_file = open(new_file_name, "w")
        doc.writexml(xml_file)
        xml_file.close()

        os.remove(old_file_name)
```

I know that in my code, I have "doc.getElementsByTagName('Volume')[0]" which denotes the first instance of the "Volume" tag, but I was just doing that as a test to see if it would work. So I'm aware that the code is working exactly as it should. But I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions, or could tell me the easiest way to apply the user input percentage to **all** of the instances of the "Volume" tag.

This is also my first attempt at Python, so if you see anything else that seems weird, please let me know.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be much happier if you use a more modern XML API, like [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (in the standard library) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/) (more advanced).

In ElementTree or lxml you get access to XPath (or something close), which allows for a much more flexible syntax in finding elements and attributes in XML documents.

In ElementTree:

```
volumes = my_parsed_xml_file.find('.//Volume')
```

...will find all occurrences of the `Volume` element.

If you stick with the current syntax, by doing:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName('Volume')[0]
```

...you're specifically asking for the zero-th (first) `Volume`.  If you want to process them all, you want a loop:

```
for volume in doc.getElementsByTagName('Volume'):
  child = volume.childNodes[0]
  // ... rest of your code inside the loop
```

If constructs like loops are unfamiliar to you, you should probably step back and read an introductory programming guide, as things will get pretty complicated quickly without some fundamentals. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Liza! That worked. I ended sticking with the minidom instead of going with ElementTree though. The loop function works great, but the only problem is that the user must input a percentage for each instance of the Volume tag. Is there an easier way to tell the raw_input to look at the last input and continue using it?

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it worked. Have fun with Python and XML, they're a great combination.